# Change how WP e-Commerce calculates price total at checkout

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, customization

My situation:

I'm selling a few products.  I need to get some options at checkout (like Do you want to add installation services?) that will affect the price, and I need to reference a custom database table to do some complex price calculations to get a total order price.

I wanted to use getshopped.org's wp e-commerce shopping cart, but somehow override the checkout page to do what I need, then return my calculated price to wp e-commerce to finish the order up.

How would I do this?  Would I use a hook?  Should I change some method that calculates the totals (without losing my changes on the next update)?  Or do I have to drop the plugin and roll my own completely?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some inspiration:

An old colleague of mine did a similar solution. He created a product, in your case called "Installation service", put it as a draft and added it with ajax when customer added it in the shopping cart, and then updated the total price. In that way the product was added to the order and the total price.

Comment: That's a good idea Elisabeth, thanks.  That solves half my problem, but not the table look up part.  I'm thinking I'll have to roll my own.